# Hamming weight of powers

Tags: ds.algorithms, co.combinatorics, space-bounded, space-time-tradeoff

Given positive integers $b$ and $e$, what is known about the space and time complexity of finding the Hamming weight (number of binary 1s) of $b^e$?

If $e\log b$ bits are available, the number can simply be calculated by standard techniques and the 1s counted.  But what techniques are possible when less memory can be used?

Comment: Why don't you compute in Chinese remainder representation, use the Chiu-Davida-Litow algorithm to convert to binary representation in logarithmic space, and then just count?

Comment: @MarkusBläser answer ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This answer expands my comment above.

You can do it with $O(\log e + \log \log b)$ space as follows:

1) First compute $b^e$ in Chinese remainder representation modulo sufficiently many primes.

2) Then use the Chiu-Davida-Litow algorithm to convert the Chinese remainder representation into binary representation. (Informatique Theoretique et Applications, Vol 35(3), pages 259-275, 2001)

3) Finally, just count the number of $1$'s.

This is a composition of a finite number of log-space computable functions, which is itself log-space computable.